# GoDaddy shared hosting with domain registed at a different registrar

Tags: domains, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I've got a shared hosting account on GoDaddy, however my domain name is registered at a seperate company.  Assuming I already know how to point my domain name to whatever I want, how do I set up GoDaddy to accept the whatever domain name I want, and how do I find the proper address for my GoDaddy hosting so that I can point my domain name to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you sign up for Godaddy shared hosting they usually send you and email afterwards with the server's IP. Once you have the IP address go to the site that is hosting your domain name and change the Host (A)Record within the DNS setting to reflect the new IP address. It will take an hour or an hour and a half based upon what the TTL is set to.

Comment: This would work if I didn't have shared hosting.  Shared hosting doesn't give you a static IP address to use.

Comment: @Ryan - I have Linux shared hosting with Godaddy and all I had to do was update my Host (A) record with the IP and everything works fine.

Comment: I didn't believe but anyhow try this solution and it works. I have my domain registered on Route53 and got shared hosting on godaddy. My plan was to host my site on EC2 but I still have subscription with godaddy so wanna save few months of EC2 usage. all i had to do was to edit A type DNS Record value to GoDaddy's shared IP. I didn't think it will work coz I can't get to my site via the IP. (not like the site I have on EC2 I can get to my site via public IP). Somehow something is clever (godaddy or Route53) enough to point to the right place even with multiple sites hosted on Godaddy. +1.

Answer (score 3):

GoDaddy's [Change nameservers for my domains](https://www.godaddy.com/help/change-nameservers-for-my-domains-664) support article will tell you what nameservers to use based on where your domain is registered and who your hosting provider is.

Comment: Do you have to change the nameservers and the DNS (A)Record?

Comment: @GavinR no need, i have setup hosted domain in godaddy

Answer (score 0):

Seems Godaddy have differnet name server for different service and listed in this new page https://in.godaddy.com/help/find-my-godaddy-nameservers-12318

Find primary domain's nameservers

Log in to your GoDaddy account.
Next to Domains, click Manage.
Click the domain you want to use, and then select the DNS Zone File tab.
The domain's nameservers display in the NS (Nameserver) section.

Changes to your domain nameservers can take up to 48 hours to propagate.

Find secondary/alias domain nameservers

Log in to your GoDaddy account.
Click Web Hosting.
Next to the hosting account you want to use, click Manage.
In the Domains section, click DNS Manager.
Click 'Change Zone' after 'Zone File Editor.' You should see a list of your aliased domains.

Find the domain you want to view the zone file for and click OK.
If you are trying to confirm nameservers for an aliased domain you recently added, scroll to the bottom of the zone file until you see the 'NS (Nameserver)' section. The nameservers listed as (Informational) will be the nameservers the domain needs to use.